# Unit testing code paths

Tags: code-smell, unit-testing

When unit testing using expectations, you define a set of method calls and corresponding results for those calls. These define the path through the method that you want to test.

I have read that unit tests should not duplicate the code. But when you define these expectations, isn't that duplicating the code, or at least the process? How do you know when you're duplicating functionality under test?

Answer (score 3):

Expectations should be different but if you're testing with a common set of expectations across several unit tests you should use variables and objects that are shared.

This is also why you have the setUp and tearDown methods for in xUnit frameworks.

Some frameworks take this one step further letting you set up with nesting such as [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Suites-and-specs) (BDD/TDD for Javascript).

Comment: Funny - there's also a Jasmin (no trailing 'e') that is a Java assembler!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how trivial the methods are that you are testing.

**Example A -- trivial code, trivial test(s)**

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }
  public SomeClass(string someString)
    {
      SomeStringProperty = someString;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeClassConstructorSetsSomeStringProperty()
{
  string testString = "abc";
  SomeClass some = new SomeClass(testString);
  Assert.AreEqual(testString, some.SomeStringProperty);
}
```

Save methods, property getters, setters and simple constructors all fall into this category.  The setup methods and assertions will be simple and resemble the code under test to the point where you would think that they are duplicative.  Many articles about how to do unit testing have trivial examples like this, and then people think unit testing doesn't look that valuable.  I don't blame them for thinking that if those are the only examples that they've seen.

**Example B -- more complex code, more tests required.**

```
public class PaymentCalculator
{
  public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }
  public int IsRecipientLikable { get; set; }

  public decimal PaymentAmount()
  {
    decimal payment = 0;
    if (DayOfMonth < 15) payment += 100;
    if (IsRecipientLikable) payment *= 6;
    return payment;
  }
}

[TestMethod]
public void PaymentOn4thForLikeablePersonIs600Dollars()
{
  var calc = new PaymentCalculator { DayOfMonth = 4, IsRecipientLikable = true };
  Assert.AreEqual(600, calc.PaymentAmount());
}
```

Obviously, this one test won't cover all the conditions of your "calculator", so you would need to write several more.

In summary, the more complex your business logic is, the more meaningful, and less-duplicative your tests can and should be.